# First POST to Azure MVC3 app very slow

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, azure

As the title implies, the first "cold" POST to our MVC3 app in the Azure cloud is very slow. Once it "spins up", the normal requests are blazing fast. The first spin-up after a brief period of rest takes a few seconds. Subsequent requests can be measured in milliseconds.

How can we keep this thing awake?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is probably due to the appplication pool unloading after a period on inactivity. The next request has to take the overhead of starting it up again.

To confirm this, you need to turn on the performance counters and look at the numbers of app domain  loads and unloads.

Either way, [this blog post](http://blog.smarx.com/posts/controlling-application-pool-idle-timeouts-in-windows-azure) explains how to fix it.

Comment: What a great answer! Thank you. This is for an API, so it is especially important! This is not a site where someone can wait around.

Comment: No probs, I had exactly the same issue myself, so I learnt the hard way!